# Port 8082 not available

Tags: port, firewall, gitblit

I installed a Jenkins server on port 8080.
Then I installed GitBlit, which usually takes port 8080 too, so that I changed to port 8082.

On the machine I can call localhost:8082, but from remote 192.168.178.3:8082 is not available.
Jenkins response works on 192.168.178.3:8080

I opened the port on the hardware firewall. Still no response.

The last thing I could image is the Windows firewall, but even after opening the port for TCP for in and out its not working?
Or where do you think the problem is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Gitblit GO, the default config for Gitblit GO will bind to localhost and will be unreachable from another machine.  Check out *server.httpBindInterface* and *server.httpsBindInterface*.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you need to do any **port forwarding** on your hardware firewall?

If you suspect Windows, you can add your program/service to the exception list in you Win Firewall settings. You can make this by going to:

```
START->Control Panel->Windows Firewall->Windows Firewall with Advanced Security
```

and modify Inbound and Outbound rules.

Comment: I tried to run 192.168.178.3:8082 on the machine with GitBlit. But its not working. So it could be a problem with the Server.
Running 192.168.178.3:8080 shows me Jenkins on that machine.
Does this help to pinpoint the problem?